# When an item in a listview is clicked, show details

Tags: javafx

I am going to show details about a movie when the movie is clicked in
a listview.
Currently, nothing happens when I click the movie.
Does anyone know how I can make this happen?
I have no idea how I am going to do this.
My code is included below.

**Controller:**

```
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import no.hiof.aleksar.oblig4.data.DataHandler;
import no.hiof.aleksar.oblig4.model.Film;

public class FilmController {
@FXML
private Label navnFilmLabel;
@FXML
private TextField beskrivelseTextField, utgivelsesdatoTextField, spilletidTextField;
@FXML
private ListView listeMedFilmer;

private int valgtFilm = 0;
private Film denValgteFilmen;
private ObservableList<Film> filmListe;

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    listeMedFilmer.setItems(DataHandler.hentFilmData());

    filmListe = DataHandler.hentFilmData();

    if (valgtFilm < filmListe.size()) {
        Film enFilm = filmListe.get(valgtFilm);
        fyllUtFilm(enFilm);
    }
}

private void fyllUtFilm(Film enFilm) {
    if (enFilm != null) {
        navnFilmLabel.setText(enFilm.getTittel());
        beskrivelseTextField.setText(enFilm.getBeskrivelse());
        utgivelsesdatoTextField.setText(enFilm.getUtgivelsesdato().toString());
        spilletidTextField.setText(String.valueOf(enFilm.getSpilletid()));
    }
}
}
```

**FXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="no.hiof.aleksar.oblig4.controller.FilmController">
   <children>
      <ListView fx:id="listeMedFilmer" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="291.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="300.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <Button layoutX="310.0" layoutY="373.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ny" />
      <Button layoutX="348.0" layoutY="373.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Rediger" />
      <Button layoutX="412.0" layoutY="373.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Slett" />
      <Label fx:id="navnFilmLabel" layoutX="312.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Film/Serie/Episode">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="27.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <GridPane layoutX="312.0" layoutY="68.0" prefHeight="208.0" prefWidth="276.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label text="Beskrivelse:" />
            <Label text="Utgivelsesdato:" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Spilletid:" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextField fx:id="beskrivelseTextField" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="138.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="10.0" />
               </font></TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="utgivelsesdatoTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
               <font>
                  <Font size="10.0" />
               </font></TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="spilletidTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <font>
                  <Font size="10.0" />
               </font></TextField>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Datahandler:**

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import no.hiof.aleksar.oblig4.model.Film;
import no.hiof.aleksar.oblig4.model.Person;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class DataHandler {
private final static ObservableList<Film> filmListe = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public static ObservableList<Film> hentFilmData() {
    if (filmListe.isEmpty()) {
        genererFilmData();
    }
    return filmListe;
}
private static void genererFilmData() {
    filmListe.add(new Film("Inception", "A thief who steals corporate secrets through the use of dream-sharing technology is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a CEO." , 148, LocalDate.of(2010, 7, 21), new Person("Leonardo", "DiCaprio", LocalDate.of(1974, 11, 11))));

    filmListe.add(new Film("The Imitation Game", "During World War II, the English mathematical genius Alan Turing tries to crack the German Enigma code with help from fellow mathematicians." , 114, LocalDate.of(2014, 12, 25), new Person("Benedict", "Cumberbatch", LocalDate.of(1976, 7, 19))));

    filmListe.add(new Film("Jobs", "The story of Steve Jobs' ascension from college dropout into one of the most revered creative entrepreneurs of the 20th century." , 128, LocalDate.of(2013, 11, 1), new Person("Ashton", "Kutcher", LocalDate.of(1978, 2, 7))));
}
}
```

Comment: why do you expect anything to happen - there isn't any eventhandler nor any listener registered anywhere .. looks like you need to read and understand a basic tutorial on how user-interaction is handled in fx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*JavaFX custom MasterDetail pane*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40106017/230513).

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722418/how-to-handle-listview-item-clicked-action

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).